# Get minutes of date using Joda-Time

Tags: java, android, date, time, jodatime

Following zulu date string is given:

```
2013-12-18T23:41:54.959Z
```

And I want to convert this to GMT and retrieve the minutes using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). I build following method:

```
public static int minutesFromDateString(final String s){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(s);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dt.toDate());

    return calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}
```

However this returns an error:

> 12-22 16:04:11.940: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "2013-12-18T23:41:54.959Z" is malformed at "13-12-18T23:41:54.959Z"

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't using a valid pattern. Your pattern says it is looking for HH:mm, your real string is far more complex. Look at the [DateTimeFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs. It looks like you want something like this: "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Comment: Correct, format pattern is wrong. But actually, no format pattern is needed. A DateTime can take an ISO 8601 formatted string like that one directly in its constructor. `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2013-12-18T23:41:54.959Z" );`

Answer (score 5):

Just set proper pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`

In your case:

```
public static int minutesFromDateString(final String s){        

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(s);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dt.toDate());

        return calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }
```

Output:

```
41
```

See docs [HERE](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html)

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by PearsonArtPhoto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20730841/642706) is correct. To add more…

## Joda-Time

With [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), no need for format pattern, and no need for Calendar class. You are working too hard.

- The DateTime class takes an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string directly in its constructor.
- Call the [`getMinuteOfHour`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getMinuteOfHour()) method on a DateTime to extract just that portion.

If you want [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT rather than a [specific time zone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html), pass the built-in constant, [`DateTimeZone.UTC`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC). Be aware that time zone could affect your minute-of-hour. Not all time zones adjust by full hours. India for example has an offset of five *and a half* hours ahead of UTC/GMT (+05:30).

```java
String input = "2013-12-18T23:41:54.959Z";
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" ); // Or, DateTimeZone.UTC;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );
int minuteOfHour = dateTime.getMinuteOfHour();
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "minuteOfHour: " + minuteOfHour );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-12-19T00:41:54.959+01:00
minuteOfHour: 41
```

## java.time

Joda-Time has been officially replaced by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. While Joda-Time continues to be updated, future work will go into the java.time classes and their extension, [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

Much of java.time has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. That work is adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

The discussion above applies to a java.time solution. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC. Apply a time zone [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
String input = "2013-12-18T23:41:54.959Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ); // Or, ZoneOffset.UTC;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant, zoneId );
int minuteOfHour = zdt.getMinute(); // Gets the minute-of-hour field.
```